# How to return 1 out of 2 values depending on input values from a function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Hi basically I would like to return 1 value if input is negative and another if input is positive. But not return both at the same time. The values returned would be used for the curve_fit function from scipy to determine my unknow parameters (a & b).

I tried using a if loop inside the function but it gives the following error:

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Here is my code:

```
#Input fitting data
PAP_Applied_H = [-5,5,10]
PAP_Eb_fit = [30.7,31.3,31.6]

#Function Fitting
def f2(x,a,b):
    if x<0:
        y=a*((1+(x/b))**2)
    else:
        y=a*((1-(x/b))**2)
    return y

params2,extras2 = curve_fit(f2,PAP_Applied_H,PAP_Eb_fit,p0=(1,15))

#Linear Fitting
linefit2 = py.polyfit(PAP_Applied_H,PAP_Eb_fit,1)
l2 = py.poly1d(linefit2)

x_new2 = list(range(-50000,1000,1))
x_line2 = list(range(-3000,3000,1))
y_func2 = f2(x_new2,params2[0],params2[1])
y_line2 = l2(x_line2)
```

So how should i change the function 'f2' such that it returns the value I want? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the function x is a list (The variable you say `input`). So do you think to determine whether the input list positive or negative..?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your `f2` function as written, except that you are passing it a `list`, rather than a single value for `x`. How do you expect it to behave if you pass it  `x=[-1,1,1,-1,1]`? Is x positive or negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input `x` is a list. You cannot check for positive or negative value for whole list. You have to check each element one by one.
Try this:

```
def f2(x,a,b):
    y=[]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i]<0:
            y.append(a*((1+(x[i]/b))**2))
        else:
            y.append(a*((1-(x[i]/b))**2))
    return y
```

Here the return value `y` is also a list of values.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

def f(x, a, b): return a * (1 -  2*abs(x)/b + (x/b)**2)

I know, it's a workaround and doesn't solve the general cae.